# trusted platform module prototype

Tags: trusted-platform-module

I have a Java card, which I like to learn more about by installing my own TPM on it. One, which I can kind of "kick the tires", install root keys, send different command to, and ... without fear of breaking anything or making it unresponsive. Does anyone know of a TPM implementation I can put on this card? when I put the card in the reader, my Windows 7 Device Manager lists it as NIST 800-73 PIV. I read some of the Bitlocker content, and it sounds like what I want but I am not sure how open it is as far as interfacing with it. What I mean is would I be able to freely implement my own functions inside the TPM at that point or not? That is basically my goal to implement my own functions/apps inside a TPM.

Comment: Did you have a look at the organisation that actually leads the TPM initiative ([the TCG](https://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/))? Will you be able to implement your own functions in a TPM? Only if you programmed it (otherwise bad things could happen?). As for the implementation request, this is off-topic here, but I *hope* the TCG community can help you with this more than we can.

Comment: @SEJPM- I did look at the TCG website; I need to do a more complete search.

Comment: I like to add one more item to this post. I think it is possible to add your own functions since vendors do the same thing; right? Each vendor has their own implementation. I just have to know the TPM implementation I am using very well so I won't mess up anything. Right? That is why I am looking for a sandbox environment.